# How can I generate a Visual Studio 2012 project targeting Windows XP with CMake?

Tags: c++, visual-studio, visual-studio-2012, cmake, windows-xp

With Visual Studio 2012 Update 1 released, I am hoping to build a C++ project to support Windows XP.  Is there a way to use CMake to generate a project that targets Windows XP?  Basically CMake would need to generate a project file that uses Platform Toolset = Visual Studio 2012 - Windows XP (v110_xp).

Answer (score 13, accepted):

According to http://www.cmake.org/Bug/view.php?id=10722 the answer is <s>no</s> yes.

Update: The bug mentioned above has been resolved with the following comment:

> Fixed in Version  CMake 2.8.11
>
> A new "generator toolset" feature has been added here:
>
> http://cmake.org/gitweb?p=cmake.git;a=commitdiff;h=7dab9977 [^]
>
> One may now run CMake from the command line with
>
> -G "Visual Studio 10" -T "v90"
>
> in order to build with a specific toolset. We've not yet added a
> first-class interface to cmake-gui for this, but one may add the cache
> entry "CMAKE_GENERATOR_TOOLSET" to contain the "-T" value before
> configuring.

You might also look at the comments made to the other answers.

Comment: As Jesper Hedlung mentioned in his answer: Newer versions of CMake support the usage of different platform toolsets.

Answer (score 17):

According to http://www.cmake.org/Bug/view.php?id=10722 the answer is now (soon) yes.

> Fixed in Version  CMake 2.8.11
>
> A new "generator toolset" feature has been added here:
>
> http://cmake.org/gitweb?p=cmake.git;a=commitdiff;h=7dab9977 [^]
>
> One may now run CMake from the command line with
>
> -G "Visual Studio 10" -T "v90"
>
> in order to build with a specific toolset. We've not yet added a
> first-class interface to cmake-gui for this, but one may add the cache
> entry "CMAKE_GENERATOR_TOOLSET" to contain the "-T" value before
> configuring.

Comment: Yes I confirm, BUT It looks Like the NMake generator does not yet support the toolset selection. in 2.8.11.rc4

Comment: It works for me if I remove the quotes, like in `-T v90`. The platform toolset of course has to be installed.

Answer (score 1):

I think you can just generate a Solution for Visual Studio 2010/2012. Open this solution, open the solution/project in visual Studio, open the properties and reconfigure the Platform toolset to v110_xp.

Then you should be fine. But I'm still searching for the solution how to setupo the command line to build v110_xp programs...

Comment: The only problem with that is that CMake will try to run again. The projects generated by CMake are not meant to be modified. It will work if you hit the ignore button, but you have to do this every build.

Answer (score 1):

I think the best way to address this problem is use CMake to build your project for Visual Studio 2010 and then open the project with Visual Studio 2012. When you do this the toolset used will be vs2010, which works for WinXP.