# CMake: how to specify the version of Visual C++ to work with?

Tags: visual-studio, visual-c++, cmake, version

I have multiple versions of Visual Studio installed (2010, 2012, 2015 trial).

How can I force CMake to generate the makefiles for a specific VS version? By default it generates for VS2015.

Answer (score 34, accepted):

First you can check what [generators](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/v3.4/manual/cmake-generators.7.html#visual-studio-generators) your CMake version does support (and how they are named):

```
> cmake.exe --help
...
The following generators are available on this platform:
...
  Visual Studio 11 2012 [arch] = Generates Visual Studio 2012 project files.
                                 Optional [arch] can be "Win64" or "ARM".    
...
```

---

Then you can give the generator with

1. `cmake.exe -G "Visual Studio 11" ..` (short name)
2. `cmake.exe -G "Visual Studio 11 2012" ..` (full name)

I prefer the later, because of its clarity. And I normally have this call in a build script wrapper:

```
@ECHO off
IF NOT EXIST "BuildDir\*.sln" (
    cmake -H"." -B"BuildDir" -G"Visual Studio 11 2012"
)
cmake --build "BuildDir" --target "ALL_BUILD" --config "Release"
```

---

The full name is transferred to an internal cached CMake variable name [`CMAKE_GENERATOR`](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/v3.4/variable/CMAKE_GENERATOR.html). So the above calls are equivalent to

3. `cmake -DCMAKE_GENERATOR="Visual Studio 11 2012" ..`

---

This gives us an interesting possibility. If you place a file called `PreLoad.cmake` parallel to your main `CMakeLists.txt` file you can force the default (if available) to take for your project there

4. `cmake.exe ..`

   *PreLoad.cmake*

   ```
   if (NOT "$ENV{VS110COMNTOOLS}" STREQUAL "")
       set(CMAKE_GENERATOR "Visual Studio 11 2012" CACHE INTERNAL "Name of generator.")
   endif()
   ```

---

Sometimes you may need to add also `-T <toolset-name>` or `-A <platform-name>` option:

5. `cmake.exe -G "Visual Studio 10" -T "v90" ..`

---

And last but not least if you are really only interested in the compiler

6. `"\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 11.0\VC\vcvarsall.bat"`

   `cmake.exe -G "NMake Makefiles" ..`

---

#### References

- [CMake command line](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/v3.4/manual/cmake.1.html)
- [What is the default generator for CMake in Windows?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6430251/what-is-the-default-generator-for-cmake-in-windows)
- [CMake: In which Order are Files parsed (Cache, Toolchain, …)?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30503631/cmake-in-which-order-are-files-parsed-cache-toolchain)
- [How can I generate a Visual Studio 2012 project targeting Windows XP with CMake?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13596816/how-can-i-generate-a-visual-studio-2012-project-targeting-windows-xp-with-cmake)

Comment: An important answer for an important question. +1 for you.

Comment: Is there a way to set the generator to be MSVC yet make it use CLANG as a compiler? It seems whatever I do once `-G"Visual Studio 15 2017 Win64"` I can't make CMake use a different compiler (Though it is compatible).

Comment: this doesn't work for me, I indicated `-G"Visual Studio 15 2017 Win64"` but still shows 
`-- The C compiler identification is MSVC 19.16.27045.0
-- The CXX compiler identification is MSVC 19.16.27045.0`

Answer (score 3):

```
cmake -G "Visual Studio 12" ..\MyProject
```